# Utilization of ports on switch

Tags: switch, switching, switchport

I have two WS-C3560E-48PD switches in the same organisation. How can I know which ports are utilized on the switches, and PC, phones, and printers?

Is there are some command used to know above issue?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you really mean, you could use the `show mac-address-table` command to see the MAC address table on a switch. This will give you the MAC addresses and the interfaces on which traffic from those MAC addresses was seen.

A MAC address for a device will tell you the OUI (manufacturer) of the ethernet interface of the device.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, which ports type you are trying to monitor? Physical, SVI's or other? 
Best way to do that in a long-term perspective is setup the SNMP credentials on a switch and add it to the monitoring system to collect the information that you need.

Fast way to see some information from switch cli is:
show int fa1/1 or gi1/1 (See the 5 minute utilization and input/output packets. Queue analysis can help also)

What do you mean about PC/Phones/Printers? Do you what to know where they connected or you want to discover that? If you know the exact ports, you may use the same commands as said.

The following command could be helpful for you: `show int | i FastEthernet|packets input|packets output|queue` Change FastEthernet for your type of Ethernet if you don't see anything.

Comment: First thanks pavel for your answer,i try to monitoring all ports online connected at the moment on this switch , and I mean also all devices used these ports on the switch ..like port 1 connected whit cisco phone and port 2 connected to PC .

Comment: You are welcome :). The following command could be helpful for you:
`show int  | i FastEthernet|packets input|packets output|queue`
Change FastEthernet for your type of Ethernet if you don't see anything.

Comment: thank you i tried  by above command but no luck , can you tell me which command  use to know which ports online at the moment ???

Comment: On the switch you can use 'show interface status' for the L2 interfaces and 'show ip int brief' for L3.